# Firebase unity authentication google signIn, downloading package removes the UI of the Unity Project

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

So I tried making a google signIn authentication in my unity project.I downloaded google-signin-plugin-1.0.4.unitypackage from https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/releases and firebase unity sdk dotNet4 FirebaseAuth.unitypackage and imported to my unity project. By doing so, my UI package from the unity project get removed and I got an error "The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". By reading the documentation on https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup, Known Error Section, as I am using .NET 4.x, so I removed Parse/Plugins/Unity.Compat.dll and Parse/Plugins/Unity.Tasks.dll. But It still removes the UI. This issue is also given on https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/issues/127. Did someone has got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I find the solution. The problem is with the unity version. It worked on Unity 2018.4.21f1 but didn't worked on 2019.2.13f1.